# Yii, invalid request on action's controller from a module

Tags: php, yii

This is the first time i am building a module in `Yii`, this module is about an `API` where i can gather data from other servers and apps, i have created the module via GII and added the module into the config file, everything works fine for now.. I created a new controller inside this `API` module with action index as usual, still everything goes fine, but when i add another action to this controller and try to access it on the browser, i get the "Your request is invalid" message, i have tried with changing the name of the controller because i have another controller with the same name but outside the module, also tried changing the action name, but still no clue.

Controller:

```
<?php 
Class ItemsController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $items = Items::model()->findAll();

        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        foreach($items as $item)
            echo json_encode($item->attributes);
    }

    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model = Items::model()->findByPk($id);

        if($model)
            return $model;
    }

    public function actionData($id)
    {
        $item = $this->loadModel($id);

        if($item)
        {
            header('Content-Type: application/json');

            echo json_encode($item);
        }

        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Data could not be found", 404);

        }
    }
}
?>
```

What is the problem on this script?

**EDIT:** the url is 127.0.0.1/APP/api/item/dat/2

Comment: What is the url that is giving you the error?

Comment: @topher i edited the question so you can see how i am trying to access the action

Comment: Does http://127.0.0.1/APP/api/items/data?id=2 return the same error?

Comment: @topher yes, it keeps returning the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using `urlManager` which by default has no rule for modules. In your `main.php` config file, add the following line into your `rules`:

```
'<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
```

And if you want to give ID add the following line too:

```
'<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
```

In order to write your own customized rules (and also be more familiar), you may find [**Yii's official document about `URL Management`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url) useful.

Comment: i tried your way, but it returns "Unable to resolve the request "api/item/data/2".

Comment: yes, i have copied the edited code, but still, i managed to fix it by going through $_GET

Comment: @nosthertus Check my update. I'm quite sure that the problem is by url rewriting and rules.

Comment: well, your last update did the work, thanks anyways, where can i learn this kind of rules?

Comment: @nosthertus you're welcome dear. I have added a reference to the answer.